# Bluetooth gone from Windows 10 / Device manager

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

Windows 10 does not seem to find my on-motherboard Bluetooth device anymore, even with 'shown hidden devices' on. It does also not appear in device manager.

I tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- Restarted multiple times
- Installed the correct drivers from my motherboard manufacturer
- Tried to add the hardware as "legacy hardware" through device manager
- Windows' Bluetooth troubleshooter
- Checked my OS for integrity (sfc /scannow)
- Disabled and enabled the bluetooth controller in the BIOS

I am becoming a bit desparate as it seems to me that I tried everything (except resetting Windows but I'm not keen on that in this stage). Any other ideas?

Comment: If you boot into a Live Linux environment is the device detected?

Comment: The device may have failed, may need replacement.

Comment: Make a Linux LiveUSB w/ ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows or on a Mac https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos

Comment: @Ramhound It does not appear on Ubuntu either (I didn't install any drivers though). Hardware failure seems a bit unlikely to me, as I used BT yesterday to connect some speakers before turning off the computer.

Comment: I have a Bljuetooth daughter card in my X230. It failed some years back, IBM replaced under warranty, I stuck it in and all is well.  That is most likely what has happened here.

Comment: I do remember that it appeared in device manager but not usable/activateable in Windows. I then uninstalled it from dev. mngr. and didn't succeed in getting it back since. So I guess that indicates that it didn't hardware fail?

Comment: If, after what you have done, it does not show up in Device Manager, then that means the Bluetooth card has failed. You need to look at your manual (online) to know if the card stands alone or is part of (say) the wireless card.

Comment: That wasn't what I was hoping for :-). I guess it will be a Bluetooth dongle from now on. Thanks for the advice!